# How do I add a timeout to dynamic stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a fairly sizeable Jenkins pipeline that we are trying to par down using dynamic stages. Unfortunately the stages we're replacing use the `options {}` construct for the stage which doesn't appear to be valid in this dynamic model. Here's an example that if you remove the options it will run fine:

```
def list = ["Stage-1","Stage-2","Stage-3","Stage-4","Stage-5","Stage-6","Stage-7","Stage-8","Stage-9","Stage-10","Stage-11","Stage-12","Stage-13","Stage-14","Stage-15"];

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Dynamic Stages') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel dynamicStages(list)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def dynamicStages(stageList) {
    def stages = [:];
                    
    for(int i=0; i < stageList.size(); i++) {
        def sname = stageList[i];
        stages[sname] = {
            option {
                timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES')
            }
            stage(sname) {
                echo "Element: $sname";
                sh 'pwd; sleep 5; echo "Hello World"'
            }
        }
    }
    
    return stages;
}
```

Is there a way to use options for dynamic stages, and if not can the timeout be implemented a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def dynamicStages(stageList) {
    def stages = [:].asSynchronized() // don't ask
                    
    for (def sname : stageList) {
        def final_name =  sname // don't ask
        stages[final_name] = {
            stage(final_name) {
                node("some_node") { // what agent should be running this?
                    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                        echo "Element: ${final_name}"
                        sh 'pwd; sleep 5; echo "Hello World"'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return stages
}
```